# How fix "blank" area when navigationBarHidden = NO

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I'm rotating a view similar to tje iTunes app. In portrait is a tableview and in landscape is photo viewver.

When I return from landscape to portrait I try to recover the navigationbar but instead get a distorted tableview, and no navigation bar.

This is what I do:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
BOOL restoreNav = NO;

if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
    (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
    [self inPortrait];
    restoreNav = YES;
} else {
    [self inLandscape];
}

if (self.landscape)
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.view = self.portrait;
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        self.view = self.landscape;
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.view = self.portrait;
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.view = self.landscape;
    }       
    [[self.navigationController view] setFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
} else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; 
}

[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a semi-fix for this in http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3262-horrible-drawing-after-hiding-navigationbar.html

This is the relevant code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
//total hack - to fix the bug where the screen layout is shagged if the device orientation
//is changed when the navigation is hidden

if ([self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:NO];
}
```

}

However, is messy again if a show up the nav bar.